# Owl Carousel is not smooth with swipe gesture

Tags: owl-carousel

I have an application that shows several images in carousel.

I noticed that while swiping from left to right (or vice-versa) the movement of images is jerky but when I click on navigator buttons (small dots at bottom, in my case) it is very smooth.

Is it a known issue? How can I improve the smoothness of image movement in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and set the `dragBeforeAnimFinish` option to `false`.

```
$(elem).owlCarousel({
  dragBeforeAnimFinish: false
});
```

You can check out Owl Carousel's options here:  https://web.archive.org/web/20160825212925/http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing